# Force C++ source file to implement header file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a plugin or an option to force *.cpp file to "implement" *.h file? This way the *.cpp file would not compile unless all declared methods were implemented. As it is now it compiles successfully when implementation is missing and if project is static library it even builds successfully.

I know it would have some problems with templates so it would be fine to force only implementation of non-template methods.

Comment: Have you considered writing a unit test that covers all declared functions?

Comment: Unit tests? Static checkers (also known as [linters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29))? Code reviews?